# Open custom outlook addin when i click send button

Tags: email, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I already have custom outlook add-in, So it will show on read email. So its working fine.

This is i want now. Is there a way that trigger or open the custom outlook add-in ive created when after sending an email, i mean clicking the send button in outlook new email, Please check the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this-

1. On-Send Feature-
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows
2. Smart Alerts and OnMessageSend and OnAppointmentSend events-
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough?tabs=xmlmanifest

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of handling the `Send` button click in Outlook like somebody from the Outlook Add-ins Team mentioned. Depending on your needs you may choose one or another. The main differences between them are listed below:

1. Ability to display a custom UI. The `OnMessageSend` and `OnAppointmentSend` event handlers displays a standard dialog box without so much configuration options and limited number of controls/buttons while `ItemSend` event allows using the [Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js-preview) to open customized dialog boxes in your Office Add-in. Read more about that in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.
2. The On-Send add-ins can't be published to the store (AppSource). It must be deployed by an organization's administrator. The `OnMessageSend` and `OnAppointmentSend` add-ins can be published to `AppSource` if its `SendMode` property is set to the `SoftBlock` or `PromptUser` option.
3. The minimum supported requirement set for the On-Send event is Mailbox 1.8 while the auto-launch events are supported starting from Mailbox 1.12. That means if you need to support earlier versions of Outlook you need to use the On-Send feature. See [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) for more information.

Read more about possible differences between the two in the [Differences between Smart Alerts and the on-send feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough?tabs=xmlmanifest#differences-between-smart-alerts-and-the-on-send-feature) section.

Comment: thanks Eugene. Do you know also any  github or packages that have an ability to list your outlook emails ? I want to retrive my emails from the outlook and display it into our system.

Comment: You need to use MS Graph for that. Also you may take a look at EWS.